# weak metric space

Tags: gn.general-topology, geometry

In the definition of a metric space,  replace the triangle inequality by the weaker inequality

*d* (*x*, *z*) ≤ *C* max {*d* (*x*, *y*), *d* (*y*, *z*)},

where C is a positive constant (depending on the "metric", but not on the points *x*, *y*, *z*). Had structures like this ever been studied?

One can associate a more or less natural topology to this "metric", calling a set *open* if every point belonging to the set has a ball of positive radius, centered at this point and contained in the set. But I cannot say much on this topology. For instance, it is not obvious (and may be not true) that a ball is an open set. Neither could I prove that this topology is Hausdorff.

Any information, reference, etc. would be welcome.

Comment: When $C=1$ I think this might hold for $p$-adic numbers... in which case the condition is stronger than the usual metric space condition, and makes $p$-adic analysis a bit easier.

Comment: Yes, for C=1, this is just the so-called *ultrametric* 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrametric_space
Though why it is called (or should be called) ultrametric is not fully clear to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they were introduced in valuation theory by Emil Artin and remain present in many contemporary treatments, including mine: see

[http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~pete/8410Chapter1.pdf](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/8410Chapter1.pdf)

especially Section 1.2 and

[http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~pete/8410Chapter2.pdf](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/8410Chapter2.pdf)

[**Added**: as RW has justly pointed out, my answer here makes sense in the context of valuation theory only.  The procedure that I give from passing from a "weak metric" to a metric is not going to work in general, I think, but only in the presence of some additional algebraic structure.  If I were the OP, I might not choose this as the accepted answer, or at least not yet.]

The basic idea here is to consider two such guys equivalent if one can be obtained from the other by the operation of raising $d$ to some positive real number power $\alpha$.  In such a way, one can make the constant $C \leq 2$ in which case one gets an actual metric.  The topology one gets in this way is easily seen to be independent of the choice of $\alpha$.

As it happens, when writing up these notes for a course I taught last spring I also thought a little bit about trying to define "balls" with respect to such a weak metric (i.e., without first renormalizing).  I didn't get anywhere with this either.

Finally, I should say that in valuation theory at least, these "weak metrics" (in the valuation theoretic context I called them "Artin absolute values" and then after the course was over decided to change to the terminology to just "absolute values", while retaining the word "norm" for such a guy which was actually a metric) come up as a useful tool but are not really studied on their own or in any deep way: I have yet to see a text on valuation theory where weak norms appear after page 20 or so.  Whether they may have wider applicability in some other context, I couldn't say...

Comment: The arguments you refer to (that for $C\le 2$ one gets an actual metric) heavily depend on an additional algebraic structure. I don't see how they would work in the general case.

Comment: @RW: That may well be.  I have only encountered the phenomenon in the setting of valuation theory, and I don't mean to imply that what I say works in the general case.  Perhaps this should not be the accepted answer...